# Deleting memory in go

Tags: c++, c, go

I am allocating memory in c++ using new which I am accessing in my go code.
Is there any way to delete this memory in go code.

This is the flow of my code :

```
func f_Go(){

    f_C(&buf);//c function
    buff := C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(buf), size) //after accessing buf we have to delete buf for avoiding memory leak
}

void f_C(char *buf){

    f_C++(&buf);//c++ function
}

void f_C++(char **buf){ //here using new I am allocating memory

*buf = new[20];
memcpy(*buf, "hhhhhhjdfkwejfkjkdj", 20);//cpy content into *buf

}
```

using like this way I am able to access buf there in go but later we have to delete this memory.
So my question is what is the way to delete this memory.

Comment: well, i don't know `c++` and `go`, but can you not create the same kind of functions for deallocation, using `delete`?

Comment: `C.free(unsafe.Pointer(buff))` should do AFAIK

Comment: @tomwilde: the C allocator is not necessarily going to be the same as the C++ allocator, so doing that kind of thing can easily cause errors (especially if the code is using the array `new`).

Answer (score 2):

You can export a second function that performs the deallocation.  Something like this should do in your C++ file:

```
extern "C" {
    void create_buf(char **buf) {
        *buf = new char[20];
        ...
    }

    void free_buf(char **buf) {
        delete[] *buf;
        *buf = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Now you have another function you can call using CGo to perform the clean up.

Comment: Why do you use such a convoluted signature with a `char **` instead of a `char *`?

Comment: No particular reason.  Just trying to stay close to what his code in the question was like.

Comment: the keywords new and delete are not available in C, so this code will not work

Comment: this '(char **buf)' means an array of char * to char strings.  That is not what was allocated.  what was allocated was a single string

Comment: @user3629249: this is obviously C++ code, so needs to be compiled with a C++ compiler.  Placing it in a `.cpp` file in the package's directory is enough to get it compiled correctly.  The `extern "C"` part just ensures C linkage for the two functions, so they can be called from C (and CGo).